# Parsing string in java while reading from file

Tags: java, string, parsing, quotes

I read line from txt file.
How i can parse this line :

```
shop "The best shop" "2006"
```

to  array of strings ?

For example:

```
 array[0] = [shop]
 array[1] = [The best shop] 
 array[2] = [2006]
```

Without double quotes and spaces ?

Comment: Tokenize, rather than parse.

Comment: Split the string on `"` to get bits inside and outside double quotes separately; then split the even-numbered elements on spaces to split the strings outside double quotes.

Comment: @CKing I'm not perfectly sure, if a regex can implement escaping via `"`. Otherwise, if so, you've got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String shop = "shop \"The best shop\" \"2006\"";

    String[] tokens = shop.split(" \"");

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        tokens[i] = tokens[i].replace("\"", "");
        System.out.println("array[" + i + "] = [" + tokens[i] + "]");
    }
```

But this is for this line only :)